# I want to set an alarm repeatedly, like yearly, monthly, weekly in android, how can i do it?

Tags: android

I'm able to set a repeating alarm on the same day, but when I try to do the same for yearly or monthly (like on the same day of every month alarm should set), it's not working.

Following is the code i have tried for the same day

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, present_calender.getTimeInMillis()+intveral,intveral, pendingIntent);
```

I tried to search the same thing in stack overflow, but I couldn't find the exact solution so that's the reason I'm posting this question again.

Can anyone suggest me the solution (if possible, please, share some sample code)

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                your_destined_class.class);
intent.setAction(your_action_name);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();
        timeOff.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND,
        **your_duration_in_ms**);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        timeOff.getTimeInMillis(),
        **your_duration_in_ms**,
        pendingIntent);
```

and set **your_duration_in_ms** to daily(24*60*60*1000) or monthly(30*24*60*60*1000) and so on

Comment: Thanks @youssefhassan.. it works fine. but i have a doubt.. for add method it takes int as second parameter,but if we use same technique to set yearly alarm time off value will be deprecated na.. so how to handle that

Comment: You can timeOff.add(Calendar.DATE,
        **your_duration_in_days**);

Comment: it might fail if month has 28 or 31 days and also if its a leap year .